# mongoose.js CastError: Cast to number failed for value "[object Object]" at path "undefined"

Tags: javascript, mongoose, schema

Using `Mongoose.js` with `node.js`.

I have this schema:

```
var Photo = new Schema({
     URL:String
    ,description:String
    ,created_by:{type:ObjectId, ref:'User'}
    ,created_at:{type:Date, default:Date.now()}
});

var User = new Schema({
    name:{type:String,index:true}
    ,email:{type:String,index:true, unique:true}
});

//Task model                                                                                                                                                                                       
var Task = new Schema({
    title:String
   ,created_by:{type:ObjectId, ref: 'User'}
   ,created:{type:Date, default:Date.now()}
   ,responses:[{
       type:Number
      ,user:{type:ObjectId, ref: 'User'}
       ,comment:String
       ,avatarURL:String
       ,photo:{type:ObjectId, ref: 'Photo'}
      ,created:{type:Date, default:Date.now()}
   }]
});

//Group model                                                                                                                                                                                      
var Group = new Schema({
     name:String
    ,tasks:[Task]
});
```

and this code errors out (group is fine, task at that idx is fine,responses is an empty array,user is valid,photo is valid):

```
var typePhoto = 6;
 var resp = {
      type: typePhoto//photo                                                                                                                                                 
      ,user: user._id
      ,photo: photo._id
 };


 group.tasks[taskIdx].responses.push(resp); //errors out here
```

at that point I get the following error:

```
/home/admin/notitws/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:434
        throw err;
              ^
CastError: Cast to number failed for value "[object Object]" at path "undefined"
    at SchemaNumber.cast (/home/admin/notitws/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/number.js:127:9)
    at Array.MongooseArray._cast (/home/admin/notitws/node_modules/mongoose/lib/types/array.js:78:15)
    at Object.map (native)
    at Array.MongooseArray.push (/home/admin/notitws/node_modules/mongoose/lib/types/array.js:187:23)
    at exports.taskAddPhoto (/home/admin/notitws/routes/group.js:1097:35)
    at Promise.exports.createPhoto (/home/admin/notitws/routes/photos.js:106:4)
    at Promise.addBack (/home/admin/notitws/node_modules/mongoose/lib/promise.js:128:8)
    at Promise.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17)
    at Promise.emit (/home/admin/notitws/node_modules/mongoose/lib/promise.js:66:38)
    at Promise.complete (/home/admin/notitws/node_modules/mongoose/lib/promise.js:77:20)
```

Any ideas on how to fix this or what may be causing it?

PS Don't know if it matters but in the call to get group I am populating `tasks.responses.user` and `tasks.responses.photo` and `tasks.created_by`.

Comment: It was the value in the database that was failing the type conversion. The value being saved was fine. It is strange that the error happens on the save and not on the find.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The "type" keyword is used by mongoose to determine the type of the field. Mongoose probably thinks that responses is of type Number instead of array.

Try:

```
responses:[{
   type: {type: Number}
   ,user:{type:ObjectId, ref: 'User'}
   ,comment:String
   ,avatarURL:String
   ,photo:{type:ObjectId, ref: 'Photo'}
   ,created:{type:Date, default:Date.now()}
}]
```

Another alternative would be to wrap your response object into a schema then:

```
responses: [Response]
```

Comment: ah, of course! Thank you! ... now it's that I get it to not crash it's not populating, but you solved the crash so thank you again!

Comment: Did you try just `default: Date.now` without the () parentheses?

Answer (score 2):

I am posting what fixed my casting to objectId. It is the story of updatedBy key of my features document. I added some comments to show you the problematic area corresponds to the casting issue.

import mongoose;

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

define objectId;

```
    var ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;
```

define the type in your schema;

```
    var featureSchema = new Schema({
        name: String,
        isSystem: { type: Number, min: 0, max: 1 },
        updatedBy: {type:ObjectId, ref:'users'}, //here I defined the field!
        updatedAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

and then insert the document via post method;

```
    app.post('/features', function (req, res){
          var feature;
          console.log("POST: ");
          console.log(req.body);
          feature = new Feature({
                   name: req.body.name,
                   isSystem: req.body.isSystem,
                   updatedBy: req.body.updatedBy, //here I insert the objectId field
                   updatedAt: new Date()
          });
          feature.save(function (err) {
                   if (!err) {
                            return console.log("created");
                   } else {
                        return console.log(err);
                   }
          });
         return res.json({ features: feature });
    });
```

and finally this is your json string. you can fire it from google chrome javascript console or a similar one;

```
    jQuery.post("/features", {
                "name": "Receipt",
                "isSystem": 0,
                "updatedBy": "528f3d44afcb60d90a000001" 
     },function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                 console.log("Post resposne:"); console.dir(data);                 
                 console.log(textStatus);                             
                 console.dir(jqXHR);
     });
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm late but if you are looking at this answer, there could be also be a reason why you are getting this error, you may have not defined "/:id" for the put/patch/delete request in your API.